# Use QML ToolTip with Label

Tags: qt, qml, label, tooltip

I'm using a [ToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tooltip.html) with a TextField. This works properly.

```
RowLayout {
    property string toolTipText

    TextField {
        hoverEnabled: true
        ToolTip.visible: tooltipText ? hovered : false
        ToolTip.text: tooltipText 
    }
}
```

But with a Label it wont work properly. 
`hoverEnabled` is not available in the Label Component. So i've tried it with a `MouseArea`

```
RowLayout {
    property string toolTipText

    Label {
        MouseArea { 
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            ToolTip.visible: tooltipText ? hovered : false
            ToolTip.text: tooltipText 
        }
    }
}
```

The [ToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tooltip.html) will be shown, but not when mouseover the [Label](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-label.html). It actually shows when entering the Window.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `hovered` is not a property of `MouseArea`, is your root object a `Page`? The `hovered` property could come from it. Use `containsMouse` to check if a `MouseArea` is hovered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MouseArea does not have the ToolTip but the Label, so that you must move it and activate it using the containsMouse property of MouseArea:

```
RowLayout {

    Label {
        text: "label"
        property string toolTipText: "message"
        ToolTip.text: toolTipText
        ToolTip.visible: toolTipText ? ma.containsMouse : false
        MouseArea {
            id: ma
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
        }
    }
}
```